# Need fix for popping hover over button?

Tags: html, css, button, hover, rollover

I need help to fix the error of my smiley button and pops when i hover over (see example below). I think the problem is related within .chatbox / form field or hover smiley. It could also be related to the div style min/max-width details etc.

Any suggestions or examples would be very grateful here.
Thx stewy

```css
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="pix/icon.png" />
<style type="text/css" href="/fonts">
    html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
    @font-face {
    font-family: vag;
    src: url(fonts/VAGRoundedStd-Light.otf);
}   
    body {
    background-color: grey;
    background-image: url(pix/bg1.png), url(pix/bg2.png);
    background-size: 1100px 100vh;
    background-position: left top, right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    .logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 3%;
}
    .cam {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 3%;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
    .livestream {
    object-fit:cover;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
    /*............... chatbox ...............*/
    
    .chatbox {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 50%; 
    transform:translateX(-50%); /* center */
    width:50vw;
    height:42px;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}
    /*... input message ...*/
    
    input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 37px;
    font-family: vag;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
    /*............. footer bar.............*/
    
    .footerbar {
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -ms-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    z-index: 2;
}
    /*........ crossfade on buttons ........*/

    #hover img{
    transition:.3s;
    position:absolute;
}
    .nohover{
    opacity:0;}
    a:hover .hover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .nohover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="pix/logo.png" width="100">
<img class="cam" src="pix/cam.jpg" width="117">
<img class="livestream" src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/bg1a.jpg">



<!--................ chatbox ..................-->

<div class="chatbox" style="min-width:400px;max-width:600px;display:flex;margin-left:15px;">
<!-- emojis gallery -->
<a class="hover" href="emojis.htm">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" height="42" style="margin-left:-32px;">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" height="42" class="nohover" style="margin-left:-32px;">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" height="42" class="hover" style="margin-left:-32px;">
</a>
<!-- input message -->
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Type Your Message" onFocus="this.value=''">
<!-- typing on/off -->
<p style="margin-top:18px;margin-right:15px;color:#ff6f6f;font-family:vag;font-size:16px;letter-spacing:1.5px;"><em><strong>Typing...</strong></em></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the following css:

```
.hover {
   position: relative;
}
.hover img{
   position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    html {scroll-behavior: smooth;}
    @font-face {
    font-family: vag;
    src: url(fonts/VAGRoundedStd-Light.otf);
}   
    body {
    background-color: grey;
    background-image: url(pix/bg1.png), url(pix/bg2.png);
    background-size: 1100px 100vh;
    background-position: left top, right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    
    font-family: Arial;
    color: darkgrey;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: .3;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
}
    .logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 3%;
}
    .cam {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 3%;
    border-radius: 60px;
}
    .livestream {
    object-fit:cover;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
    /*............... chatbox ...............*/
    
    .chatbox {
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 50%; 
    transform:translateX(-50%); /* center */
    width:50vw;
    height:42px;
    background-color: #2f2f2f;
    border-radius: 0px 30px 30px 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}
    /*... input message ...*/
    
    input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 37px;
    font-family: vag;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
    /*............. footer bar.............*/
    
    .footerbar {
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -ms-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -moz-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    z-index: 2;
}
    /*........ crossfade on buttons ........*/

    #hover img{
    transition:.3s;
    position:absolute;
}
.hover img.nohover{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
    .nohover{
    opacity:0;}
    a:hover .hover{
    opacity:0;
}
    a:hover .nohover{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="pix/logo.png" width="100">
<img class="cam" src="pix/cam.jpg" width="117">
<img class="livestream" src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/bg1a.jpg">



<!--................ chatbox ..................-->

<div class="chatbox" style="min-width:400px;max-width:600px;display:flex;margin-left:15px;">
<!-- emojis gallery -->
<a class="hover" href="emojis.htm">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley.png" height="42" style="margin-left:-32px;">
<img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" height="42" class="nohover" style="margin-left:-32px;">
</a>
<!-- input message -->
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="Type Your Message" onFocus="this.value=''">
<!-- typing on/off -->
<p style="margin-top:18px;margin-right:15px;color:#ff6f6f;font-family:vag;font-size:16px;letter-spacing:1.5px;"><em><strong>Typing...</strong></em></p>
</div>
```

Is that you wanted??